# How to convert grayscale image to given color monchrome image in PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, image-conversion

I see matrix parameter in `convert` function, but it's description is unclear. It says, that it should be 4- or 12- tuple w/o explanation of component meaning.

I tried to apply it to my grayscale image, but failed.

The code:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('myimage.png', 'rb') as fp:
    #matrix = (0, 1, 0, 1)
    matrix = (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
    im = Image.open(fp)
    im = im.convert('RGB', matrix)
    plt.imshow(im)
    plt.show()
```

throws

```
 ValueError: image has wrong mode
```

in Image.py code

```
    if matrix:
        # matrix conversion
        if mode not in ("L", "RGB"):
            raise ValueError("illegal conversion")
        >>>>>> im = self.im.convert_matrix(mode, matrix)
        return self._new(im)
```

which I also don't understand, because there is no throwing code here, just referencing an object. I can't trace into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this and maybe have a palettised image:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PIL import Image

# Open and ensure in RGB mode - in case image is palettised
im = Image.open('toystory.png').convert('RGB')

# Crude conversion to black and white using 20% red, 50% green and 30% blue
matrix = (0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.0)

result = im.convert('RGB',matrix)

result.save('result.png')
```

That converts this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

---

If you change the matrix to the following, it will swap the Red and Blue channels:

```
matrix = (0,0,1,0, 0,1,0,0, 1,0,0,0)
```

[image]

Comment: My misunderstanding was I didn't knew both source and destination images should be `RGB`. It is not 100% logical.